# Cleaning up in outer Bash script following inner script failure

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following method in Bash in a file called `outer-script.sh`:

```
test_service() {
    nohup java -jar target/outer-runner.jar > service.log 2>&1&
    echo $! > runner-process.pid
    ./inner-script.sh
    kill `cat runner-process.pid`
}
```

`inner-script.sh` can throw `exit 1` - I have `set -e` in `outer-script.sh` so the outer script will stop running if the inner one throws `exit 1`. That's all good, but it doesn't call the `kill` line in the event of a failure!

I've tried adding

```
trap "{ kill `cat runner-process.pid` }" EXIT
```

immediately below the closing bracket of `test_service()` but in the event of a failure I get the error

```
./outer-script.sh: exit trap: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

and the process isn't killed, so I suspect this isn't the correct syntax. I've tried the syntax used in a few other tutorials, but surprisingly none are particularly clear.

What is the correct way to ensure that the process is killed when `inner-script.sh` returns with `exit 1`?

Comment: try `trap '{ kill $(< runner-process.pid) ; } EXIT` ? Good luck.

Comment: You missed the second ', but that's spot on, thanks. If you add it as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: You don't need a pid file. `java_pid=$!`, followed by `kill $java_pid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
trap '{ kill $(< runner-process.pid) ; }' EXIT
```

I'm not certain that you need single-quotes VS dbl-quotes, but I generally like to use single quotes when I can to eliminate some order-of-evaluation issues.

Anytime to create a process group `{ ... ; }` (inside `{}`), you need a terminating `;` before the closing `}` char.

Using `$(< pidFile)` is a more process efficient shorthand for grabbing the contents of a file. Think about what `<` normally does. Same here.

The `$( ..cmds ..)` is the modern version of back-tic cmd substitution. Join the 90's and stop using back-tics, unless you need your code to run under the true Bourne Shell `/bin/sh`.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `set -e`, use the following syntax :

```
./inner-script.sh || { kill `cat runner-process.pid`; exit 1; }
```

If inner-script.sh fails it will execute the left-hand expression of the `||`, killing and exiting.

Comment: @shellter's comment fixed it, but thanks for an alternate option. There are other things in `outer-script.sh` that can throw errors that I'd like to be fatal, so can I use this solution with `set -e`? Or would I have to add `||` to the end of every command that I think would fail?

Comment: You would indeed have to test for error at every command, which I agree is not very alluring in your case.

Comment: OK thanks. Well it's useful to know - I have other situations where I could use it.